# Бот перестает работать на моменте принятия сообщений, и ответа на них

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

```
import vk_api 
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import 
VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType 

token = '55d012ad5ffa0cd6190a272bfc1a6e433a551524c5feb0e8bbad041eae56b1fe66e0c30ae612d87bde4c7' 
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token) 
vk._auth_token() 
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll( vk, 204894729 ) 

print ('У Хьюстона нет проблем, бот работает') 

while True: 
 for event in longpoll.listen(): 
 if event.type == 
 VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: 
 mesg = event.obj['text'] 
 peer_id = event.obj['peer_id'] 

 if mesg == 'Привет. Это проверка бота': 
 vk.method ('message.send',{'peer_id':peer_id, 'message':'Всё хорошо, бот - готов!', id:0 })
```

Доходит до момента принта, пишет что проблем нет. Печатаю ему сообщение, он выдает:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\booty.py", line 18, in 
vk.method ('message.send',{'peer_id':peer_id, 'message':'Всё хорошо, бот - готов!', id:0 })
File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 668, in method
raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] Unknown method passed

Process finished with exit code 1

Пробовала менять версию лонгда в вк, ничего не меняется

Comment: Спасибо большое, перепроверю 

Answer (score 2):

У VK API нет метода, который называется `message.send` (о чем сообщение в ошибке и говорит). Скорее всего, Вам нужен метод `messages.send`.
См. [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send).